# Tool to test the loading performance and the size of front-end libraries

Tags: web, software-testing

I am looking for a web page that allows me to search for a certain front-end library by name and know its at some load performance statistics.

Also the web page should show alternatives with better performance (size, load speed, etc).

Does anyone know any tool that you don't have to put the URL to see metrics of specific libs (load performance in the browser)?

Answer (score 0):

BundlePhobia (https://bundlephobia.com/) can shows size and performance of NPM libraries:

[image]